# Difference between bootstrap estimations and full data estimations

Tags: bootstrap

Good day. I am using an ensemble machine learning algorithm (SuperLearner) to predict XYZ. I'm finding that there is quite a difference between the predicted XYZ when using the full data and the predicted XYZ when using bootstrap samples. Where the full data estimations are not encompassed by the 95% CI of the bootstraps estimations (using the percentile method).

Does anyone have any suggestions on trouble shooting this issue?

EDIT: I found a great article that helps one diagnose specific issues with your bootstrap estimation.

http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/cjs.5550340103/pdf